# Solution to an excel/python flask web server with xlwings

Tags: python, excel, flask, xlwings

I have a complicated excel file that is a custom calculator with many formulas and macros. We input width, length, and a few other choices and get the feasibility checks, springs and tubes for the window blinds. Now, the problem is I've to use all this logic in the website I'm making in ReactJS.
I tried to migrate the excel to js but it was too much work and very complicated with all the formulas and references.
So I made a Python script with a webserver that receives the inputs and opens the excel file, gives it the inputs and outputs the result and sends them back in a json format. I then checked if it's suitable for multiple user requests but it's not. It took 8.9s to process one request and put all other requests on hold until first one was finished. I also used waitress to host the app.

I'm not sure what to do, does anyone have any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your comfortable with python and all you need is json, just use a pure python webapp and export the data in excel to sqlite or mysql. There is no way to optimize an excel file for web requests, especially with xlwings.